# "override func scrollViewDidScroll" call multi times. I want to call one time only

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I make pagination.
`override func scrollViewDidScroll` method called multiple times when I scroll.
So `loadMore` method is called many times too.
I want to call `loadMore()` method only one time when I scroll.

How can I solve it?

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height / 3 {
        loadMore()
    }
}

// pagination
func loadMore() {
    // if posts on the server are more than shown
    if page <= prePage {
        // increase page size
        page = page + 3
        prePage = page

        self.posts.removeAll()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        Api.Post.observeTopPosts(page: self.page) { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            print(post)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue you probably need to implement a `Bool` value which will determine whether or not to call the `loadMore` function.

Create a `var` which will determine whether your function has been called:

```
var hasLoaded = false
```

Then in your `scrollViewDidScroll` method add the following:

```
  override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height / 3 {

        //If we haven't loaded data then call the function
        if !hasLoaded{

           loadMore()

           //Data has been loaded so set hasLoaded to true
           hasLoaded = true
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that I have read your question correctly this should solve the issue or at least get you started in the right direction...

Comment: No problem :) Glad you got it sorted :)